# Why Spark DataFrame doesn't have saveAsORCFile() method in Java?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

```
JavaRDD<Record> dataTable = sc.textFile("hdfs://path/to/files/hdfs").map(
     new Function<String, Record>() {
       public Record call(String line) throws Exception {
         String[] fields = line.split(",");
         Record sd = new Record(fields[0], fields[1], fields[2], fields[3]);
         return sd;
       }
});

 HiveContext hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc);
 DataFrame dataFrameAsORC = hiveContext.applySchema(dataTable, Record.class);
 dataFrameAsORC.saveAsORCFile("/to/hadoop/path");//does not compile
```

I am using Spark 1.4 and I have found this [Spark-JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2883) where it is mentioned that saveAsORCFile support in 1.4 release but I can't find it in JavaDoc of DataFrame.

I am new to Spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got this working thanks to [Holden's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/572083/holden) comment:

> [Scala] implicit conversions aren't supported in Java, instead you should use
>   the standard save API for dataframes and specify the orc type when
>   saving

Here is the code using OP's example:

```
JavaRDD<Record> dataTable = sc.textFile("hdfs://path/to/files/hdfs").map(
     new Function<String, Record>() {
       public Record call(String line) throws Exception {
         String[] fields = line.split(",");
         Record sd = new Record(fields[0], fields[1], fields[2], fields[3]);
         return sd;
       }
});

// Pretty sure you can use HiveContext interchangeably here but I had
// better luck with SQLContext
SQLContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc);

// Schema for the DataFrame is created automatically from Record.class
DataFrame dataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(dataTable, Record.class);
// Record.class needs all the fields with getters/setters
// Need to do a select first or else save doesn't work
// not sure what fields OP's Record has, so I made some up
dataFrame.select("id", "field_one", "field_two", "create_tmsp")
   .save("/to/hadoop/path", "org.apache.spark.sql.hive.orc", SaveMode.ErrorIfExists);
```

Note: org.apache.spark.sql.hive.orc comes from spark-hive.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
   <version>${spark.version}</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

saveAsORCFile is an [implicit method](http://daily-scala.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/implicit-methods.html) on the dataframe.

You must first import it like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.orc._
```

Before your code.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I did import that even before posting question here it doesn't resolve saveAsOrfile btw I am using Java do I need to use scala

Comment: Implicit conversions aren't supported in Java, instead you should use the standard save API for dataframes and specify the orc type when saving.